# spring conditionally loading xml resource

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to load xml configuration file dynamically based on property existing or not.
And I am using spring @Conditional to check whether property exists or not.

```
@Configuration
@Conditional(CheckPropertyConfiguration.Condition1.class)
@ImportResource("webapp/WEB-INF/myContext.xml")
public class CheckPropertyConfiguration {

    public void test(){
        System.out.println("init .............test");
    }
    static class Condition1 implements ConfigurationCondition {
        @Override
        public ConfigurationPhase getConfigurationPhase() {
            System.out.println("getConfigurationPhase.............");
            System.out.println(System.getProperty("api.key"));
            return ConfigurationPhase.PARSE_CONFIGURATION;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
            System.out.println("checking property exist or not: " + System.getProperty("api.key"));
            return System.getProperty("api.key") != null;
        }
    }
}
```

And this bean is configured in my applicationContext.xml file

```
<bean class="com.cm.service.impl.CheckPropertyConfiguration" init-method="test" />
```

When the application is started, sysout in test() is running and showing the output on console.
But for some reason, getConfigurationPhase() and matches() methods are not called by spring framework to check the property exists or not.

Please help to to load my configuration file dynamically.

Comment: Why mix xml and java config? Do you have `<context:annotation-driven />` or `<context:component-scan />` in your xml config? If not annotations will be ignored.

Comment: You are correct. I was missed . After adding this tag, it is working. With out using annotation approach, can we load xml resource dynamically? Please suggest the way, if it is possible?

Comment: I'm not sure if conditions work in XML I guess not. But why not drop xml and use java instead.